# Subsetting data using regular expressions in R

Tags: regex, r, substring

I want to extract specific information from within a column in a data frame and add it on to a new column in the same data frame. The complication lies in the fact that some rows do not have the information I want to extract (the 6 characters after "UniProt:") at all, while others have multiple occurrences - I want these to be displayed accordingly as this column contains the identifiers in my data frame.

Here's an example; I've copied a few rows of the column Fasta.headers from my data frame:

Row 1:

> H05C05.1c;CE43771;WBGene00019157;status:Partially_confirmed;UniProt:H2L0A8;protein_id:CCD72193.1;>H05C05.1a;CE37385;WBGene00019157;status:Partially_confirmed;UniProt:Q9TXU2;protein_id:CCD72188.1

Row 2:

> C02B10.5;CE16802;WBGene00015330;status:Partially_confirmed;UniProt:O44447;protein_id:CCD61167.1

Row 3:

> ZK1127.4;CE07643;WBGene00022851;status:Confirmed;protein_id:CCD73716.1

Row 4:

> T27C4.4a;CE21211;WBGene00003025;locus:lin-40;status:Confirmed;UniProt:O61907;protein_id:CCD74255.1;>T27C4.4b;CE21212;WBGene00003025;locus:lin-40;status:Confirmed;UniProt:Q76NP4;protein_id:CCD74256.1;>T27C4.4d;CE33331;>F54F2.9;CE39158;WBGene00018836;status:Confirmed;UniProt:P34454;protein_id:CCD71243.1

I want the output to be:

```
H2L0A8;Q9TXU2
O44447

O61907;Q76NP4;P34454
```

Comment: Consider providing the output of, e.g., `dput(d$Fasta.headers[1:4])` in the future so that it's easier for people to recreate your data.

Comment: I am posting a link to a very useful regex learning platform: http://leaverou.github.io/regexplained/

Answer (score 6):

Here [strapplyc](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gsubfn/docs/strapply) from the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) extracts the desired strings from `x` and [sapply](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/sapply) collapses multiple strings into a single string separated by semicolons:

```
library(gsubfn)
sapply(strapplyc(x, "UniProt:([^;]*)"), paste, collapse = ";")
```

giving:

```
[1] "H2L0A8;Q9TXU2"        "O44447"               ""                    
[4] "O61907;Q76NP4;P34454"
```

where `x` is:

```
x <-  c("H05C05.1c;CE43771;WBGene00019157;status:Partially_confirmed;UniProt:H2L0A8;protein_id:CCD72193.1;>H05C05.1a;CE37385;WBGene00019157;status:Partially_confirmed;UniProt:Q9TXU2;protein_id:CCD72188.1",
  "C02B10.5;CE16802;WBGene00015330;status:Partially_confirmed;UniProt:O44447;protein_id:CCD61167.1",
    "ZK1127.4;CE07643;WBGene00022851;status:Confirmed;protein_id:CCD73716.1",
    "T27C4.4a;CE21211;WBGene00003025;locus:lin-40;status:Confirmed;UniProt:O61907;protein_id:CCD74255.1;>T27C4.4b;CE21212;WBGene00003025;locus:lin-40;status:Confirmed;UniProt:Q76NP4;protein_id:CCD74256.1;>T27C4.4d;CE33331;>F54F2.9;CE39158;WBGene00018836;status:Confirmed;UniProt:P34454;protein_id:CCD71243.1")
```

**ADDED** some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using the infrequently used: `regmatches<-`

```
regmatches(x,gregexpr("UniProt:.{7}",x),invert=TRUE) <- ""
gsub("UniProt:","",x)
#[1] "H2L0A8;Q9TXU2;"
#[2] "O44447;"
#[3] ""
#[4] "O61907;Q76NP4;P34454;"
```

You can also get there with lookaheads and lookbehinds specifying `perl=TRUE` to the regex:

```
sapply(regmatches(x,gregexpr("(?<=UniProt:).+?(?=;)",x,perl=TRUE)),
       paste,collapse=";")

#[1] "H2L0A8;Q9TXU2"        "O44447"              
#[3] ""                     "O61907;Q76NP4;P34454"
```